# How to get logs of jobs created by a cronjob?

Tags: cron, kubernetes

Seems that `kubectl logs` doesn't support cronjob. It says

> error: cannot get the logs from *v1beta1.CronJob: selector for *v1beta1.CronJob not implemented

Currently I check the logs of all relative jobs one by one.

Is there any simple command or tool to get these logs?

---

I did some research on bash script and modified [edbighead's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647683/how-to-get-logs-of-jobs-created-by-a-cronjob/53648331#53648331) to better suit my needs.

```
# cronJobGetAllLogs.sh: Get all logs of a cronjob.
# example:
# ./cronJobGetAllLogs.sh [Insert name of cronJob]

jobs=( $(kubectl get jobs --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | awk "/$1-[0-9]+/{print \$1}" | sort -r ) )
for job in "${jobs[@]}"
do
    echo Logs from job $job
    pod=$(kubectl get pods -l job-name=$job --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name")
    kubectl logs $pod
done
```

```
# cronJobGetLatestLog.sh: Get log of latest job initiated by a cronjob.
# example:
# ./cronJobGetLateestLog.sh [Insert name of cronJob]

job=$(kubectl get jobs --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | awk "/$1-[0-9]+/{print \$1}" | sort -r | head -1)
pod=$(kubectl get pods -l job-name=$job --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name")
kubectl logs $pod
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From documentation of [CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) and [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)

> A Cron Job creates Jobs on a time-based schedule
>
> ...
>
> A job creates one or more pods and ensures that a specified number of them successfully terminate.

All you need is to view logs for a pod that was created for the job.

1. Find your job with `kubectl get jobs`. This will return your CronJob name with a timestamp
2. Find pod for executed job `kubectl get pods -l job-name=your-job-@timestamp`
3. Use `kubectl logs your-job-@timestamp-id` to view logs

Here's an example of bash script that does all the above and outputs logs for every job's pod.

```
jobs=( $(kubectl get jobs --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name") )
for job in "${jobs[@]}"
do
   pod=$(kubectl get pods -l job-name=$job --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name")
   kubectl logs $pod
done
```

Comment: This is similar to what I'm doing now. However I have to iterate through every jobs and copy-paste job name multiple times. Do you know how to combine these commands into one and prevent copy-paste?

Comment: That's great! Unfortunately I can't test it right now. I'll mark it as answer tomorrow after I test it. Thank you.

Comment: I am actually using stern from wercker to view logs.  https://github.com/wercker/stern.  Might make it easier to get the logs regardless if its pod created by job, deployment or sts.

Comment: What shell is the script? I get `1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.

Comment: @rwst `#!/bin/sh`